# JSON formatting in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

Bit confused.

I'm using jackson to parse JSON strings into maps that will then be accepted in elasticsearch.

That works fine.

However due to the JSON specifications, all integers and other formats need to be sent through as a string - aka - `"key":"value"`. But then elasticSearch sees them as strings, not numbers. Which makes totaling values like user ratings not possible when it should be trivial.

How can I use the JSON format to input numbers/integers into elasticsearch?

Is there a way around this?

Comment: code and error messages would help

Comment: Sure. the first part of JSON input {"positive score":"0",,"publishedAt":"2017-09-07T15:35:34.000Z"} is read as String:String and not String:Object which is accepted by elasticsearch. When I change it to "score":0 I get a parse error by jackson - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token... So how can I use the JSON format to input numbers/integers into elasticsearch?

Comment: the code i'm using to send the json data to jackson is      `try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(addedDir))){

    for (String line; (line = br.readLine())!= null;) {
        System.out.println("#" + this.counter + " processing " + line);
        this.storeMap(this.convertToMap(line));
this.counter++;


    }
}`

Comment: and the double comma in the example JSON above was my pasting mistake in this stackoverflow textbox, not in the original code

Comment: I found the solution. I was sending object to jackson but using `hm = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {});` where i should have used `hm = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});` - chaging the 2nd string inthe typerference to ype object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to create a mapping for your index.

Mapping is the process of defining how a document, and the fields it contains, are stored and indexed. For instance, use mappings to define:

- which string fields should be treated as full text fields.
- which fields contain numbers, dates, or geolocations.
- whether the values of all fields in the document should be indexed into the catch-all _all field.
- the format of date values.
- custom rules to control the mapping for dynamically added fields.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

If you already have a some existing data that you don't want to lose you'll need to reindex after updating your mapping.  Due to how ES indexes data you can not change the type after it's been created.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html

Comment: Thanks for this. It goes above and beyond my question by providing understanding that should hoepfully help prevent future issues. Cheers!